# Angular2 escape slash Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I want to create a pipe in angular 2 which will replace the '\' in the given string which is used to escape special characters.

what i have done till now,

pipe class is as follows

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'escapeSlashPipe'
})

export class EscapeSlashPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform (value: string): any{
    value = value.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
    return value;
  }
}
```

html

```
<p>{{message | escapeSlashPipe}}</h4>
```

Example input

```
"ghda\'nja asda\\dasda dasj\' \"das\'da\\d as\\as\\sad"
```

then it should return

```
"ghda'nja asda\dasda dasj' das'da\d as\as\sad"
```

It should replace only the slash which is used for escaping characters.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting, because I have tried your code and its working properly fine. I am getting the expected result.

Comment: Its giving me the same output as the input, same string is returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `value.replace(/\\"/g, '"');` you are selecting the following sequence of characters: `\"` and replacing them with the following character `"`.

So, you see, it only works with the double quotes.

You can use something different:

```
let value = "Lorem \\\" ipsum \\' dolorem \\\\ javascript";
// value: Lorem \" ipsum \' dolorem \\ javascript

// Because JavaScript is already able to escape characters by itself
// So I needed to escape also the backslash

value = value.replace(/(\\)(\W)/g, '$2');
// value: Lorem " ipsum ' dolorem \ javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ghda\'nja asda\\dasda dasj\' das\'da\\d as\\as\\sad".replace(/\'/g,"'")
```

Can you try the above and let me know. It returns the following for me,

```
"ghda'nja asda\dasda dasj' das'da\d as\as\sad"
```